# Inhomogeneous magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If $B=C\hat{z}+f(y)\hat{y}$ is an inhomogeneous magnetic field where $C$ is a constant, how is it possible to find out what the function $f(y)$ is?

Comment: Use Gauss' Law $\nabla\cdot B=0$

Comment: Question: Where do you have this problem from?

Comment: The question has no solution. No **in**homogeneous field where the $y$ component is *only* a (non-constant) function of $y$ exists.

Comment: @Rob Jeffries, see my answer. I worked it out explicitly and came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider Gauss' Law. This is given by:

$\nabla \cdot B=0$, where $B$ is the magnetic field vector.

We can work this out, recall that $\nabla = \partial_x e_x + \partial_y e_y +\partial_z e_z$ therefore the standard inner product gives:

$\nabla \cdot B = \partial_x B_x + \partial_y B_y + \partial_z B_z = \partial_y f(y) + \partial_z C = \partial_y f(y)=0$.

Therefore we get by integration that $f(y)=f(x,z)$, so with that I mean that $f(y)$ has no dependence on $y$ and it could only be a constant or a function of $x,z$ or one of them.

The reason why it is inhomogeneous is because of the $x,z$ dependence. Since this is given we can rule out the possibility that $f=constant$, so we have $f=f(x,z)$.

*Edit*: The question is a bit tricky since it asks you to calculate a function $f(y)$ which depends clearly on $y$ but then it also states that the magnetic field has to be inhomogeneous. When we say that $f(y)$ is constant, this means that $B$ is not inhomogeneous but when we say $f(y)=f(x,z)$ this contradicts that $f$ is a function of $y$. So something weird must be going on!

Hope this helps a bit!

Comment: I think f(y) has to be f(y) = k, where k is a constant because f(y) can't equal f(x,z).